# Create script auto init

Tags: scripts

How can I do for execute this script when I init the system? Thanks.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

lima start
lima login
```

This is the web from the app: https://install.meetlima.com/#linux

Thank you!

Comment: What's `lima`? If it's a graphical tool, starting it at system init time won't work, as the graphical environment hasn't been set up yet.

Comment: I put a link that explain the product. The soft of lima are non graphical, you need konsole to run. Then I created and script to sume up the process but I don't know how can I do to run the script at ini the computer. So sorry, my english isn't very good.